# Appsflyer OneLink redirects to App Store instead of already installed app if page was reloaded

Tags: cookies, deep-linking, appsflyer

OneLink works fine around the web app in regular state.

We need to redirect user to App *Login/HomeScreen* if user navigate to */login* in browser.

But,

- if user **write the link directly in address line**, it will redirect him/her to App Store.
- if user **reload exisiting page**, it can redirect him/her to App Store too

I suspect there is a problem with Cookie, but I could not identify which one and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Missing some info about the browser here as the behaviour you are talking about may differ between them.
It's possible that a specific param is missing here but need to know the info about the OS as well.
If you can contact the support, they will be happy to help .